# Exception: Unsupported Android Plugin version: 3.6.3. Flutter Android Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, android-studio

i'm having trouble while running my app.
I'm getting Exception: Unsupported Android Plugin version: 3.6.3. error.
Can any one help me to fix that?
I've also tried to change the graddle version but it doesn't seems to work also.
Attaching screenshot of flutter doctor and my error.
Thanks in advance.
[image: Error]
[image: Flutter Doctor]

Answer (score 0):

You need a compatible version of gradle with your android studio. So if you have version 4.1 you need gradle 6.5 or greater. Try changing **build.gradle** and **gradle-wrapper.properties**

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: This is not acceptable. I am experiencing the same issue with flutter 2.2.3. According to the documentation you linked, I have set my gradle version to 7.0.2 and AGP to 7.0.1 and the same message appears. This seems to be more of an issue with flutter than with gradle

Answer (score 0):

Check if your android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties present

Also the error because git merge mistake

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue...solved it buy upgrading the android gradle to the latest version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).